# Cryptic error messages

Tags: dojo

We're actively developing using the Dojo toolkit and we noticed that while looking at the browser console in different browsers (for example Opera and Chrome) we notices some differences in the information that is displayed, usually very crucial information.

For example, we made a `dijit/form/Select` like this:

```
<select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-props="store: datalagenStore labelAttr: 'naam'"></select>
```

Notice that we forgot a comma between the `store` and the `labelAttr` property. When looking at Google Chrome, our console returned:
[image: Chrome console]

On the other hand, Opera returned:
[image: Opera console]

As you can see, Opera clearly returns the message that it can't parse the properties and it even says what's it expectin. In Chrome I don't get these messages. Personally I like developing using Opera, but many colleagues of mine use Google Chrome for development, but without proper error messages they usually have a hard time debugging.

Is there a reason both browsers display other information (afaik Firefox shows the same info as Chrome, so atm I'm only aware of Opera being the exception)? Can we somehow change it so Chrome would also display the same info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to expand the error in Chrome by clicking on the second triangle, you will see the same error message.

Comment: How funny is that, I never noticed the second arrow until now. Thanks.